# ODATA: Special Character in URL

Tags: odata

I am facing an issue in creating a ODATA URL.

For the Following URL,

https://xxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codataapi/CorporateAccountHasContactPersonCollection?$filter=AccountID eq '1000024'

Result :

```
- <m:properties>
    <d:ObjectID>00163E10AD0B1ED686EF458B4E8C51D5</d:ObjectID> 
    <d:ParentObjectID>00163E10AD201EE5A4F0B592DE751AE8</d:ParentObjectID
    <d:AccountID>1000024</d:AccountID> 
    <d:ContactID>1002636</d:ContactID>
    <d:FunctionCode>Z021</d:FunctionCode> 
    <d:Mobile>+33 123456789</d:Mobile> 
    <d:Phone>+33 987654321</d:Phone> 
  </m:properties>
```

Same for result when i change filter to `FunctionCode`
https://xxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codataapi/CorporateAccountHasContactPersonCollection?$filter=FunctionCode eq 'Z021'

But When I search with filter `Phone`

https://xxxxxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codataapi/CorporateAccountHasContactPersonCollection?$filter=Phone eq '+33 123456789'

**URL doesnt work at all.**  Is it becuase of special character "+" in Phone Number

I tried with $filter=endswith(Phone, '123456789'), It worked fine. But this is not solution i am looking for.

Can any one suggest another ways?

Thank you 
Regards
Prat

Comment: Have you tried using `%2B` instead of the special character `+` in the url?

Comment: @AndreF : $filter=Phone eq '%2B 123456789'  , I tried this one , But no luck.

Comment: Try this `$filter=Phone eq '%2B 33123456789'`

Comment: or if we're looking for an exact match this `$filter=Phone eq '%2B33 123456789'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that these special characters has different meaning when used in URLs. The JavaScript “encodeUri” or  “encodeUriComponent” does not solve this problem.

Here is the list of the special characters that needs to be replaced when used in the OData queries:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226544(SQL.80).aspx

The special character `+` Indicates a space (and spaces cannot be used in a URL) so you need to replace the character's with its hexadecimal value, in this case `%2B`.

Your corrected filter should then be `$filter=Phone eq '%2B33 123456789'`.

Find a good article [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmshop/archive/2015/12/21/crm-odata-rest-queries-and-special-characters).